# Linux Mint 18 apt-get update error: Connection Failed in some sources

Tags: linux-mint, apt, repository

When I run ``sudo-apt-get update`, some files cannot be downloaded:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
```

More error messages:

```
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What I have done:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

But the problem still persists.

Here is what is in my `sources.list.d/` directory, in case it gives useful information:

```
maarten-baert-simplescreenrecorder-xenial.list
neovim-ppa-stable-xenial.list
nodesource.list
official-package-repositories.list
vscode.list
yarn.list
```

How can I fix this? This is my first error for `apt-get` on linux mint 18, and Google gives no useful result.

Comment: This seems a networking problem. Does your organisation, ISP or Internet package allow unrestricted Internet access? Your IP address/network may also be blacklisted, Indonesia is quite known for hacking (yes, I know it is a long stretch, but I have got to say it); this also may be a transient network problem, try again.

Comment: alright, at least I have a bit clue about what is wrong here. That point makes a lot of sense. 

I'll try to update with a different provider or try another time. Thanks.

Comment: `http://vxcube.com/tools/ip/1.1.1.1/threat` open it on a browser, replacing 1.1.1.1 with your IP address. What does it show?